# How to redirect ServerAlias on Apache2 or mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a Virtual Host in Apache

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
   ServerName example.eu
   ServerAlias www.example.eu
   ServerAlias www.somethingElseThanExample.net
   DocumentRoot "/something"
   <Directory "something">
       Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Allow from all
        Order allow,deny
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to redirect

`www.somethingElseThanExample.net` to `www.somethingElseThanExample.net/foo/`

This has to work for homepage and for internal pages so that

`www.somethingElseThanExample.net/bar/` to `www.somethingElseThanExample.net/foo/bar/`

Is it possible to do it with Apache `mod_rewrite` through my htaccess? How do I do this in each case?

What if i need to have this result ONLY for homepage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to have access to your VirtualHost, then you could add the following to your `<Directory>` section:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.somethingElseThanExample.net [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo/
RewriteRule (.*) /foo/$1 [R=302,L]
```